# Starting with verb in bullet list

Tags: verbs, lists, parallelism

My colleague wrote a presentation and I wonder if he is correct or not.

1. The SDK is super cool
2. Provides this unique feature
3. Ensures wonderful capabilities

Is it OK that each item in the bullet list starts with a verb without a noun? Shall I rewrite it this way?

1. The SDK is super cool
2. The SDK provides this unique feature
3. It ensures wonderful capabilities

Comment: I happened to see a similar use in the man page of [git rev-parse](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse), the `--stop-at-non-option` section. At first glance I thought a `'` was missing before I realized the subject was omitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bulleted lists can contain anything. They don't need to be complete sentences, for example:

- Mad
- Bad
- Dangerous to know

Comment: my question was if it is OK to have grammatically incorrect sentences

Comment: Complete sentences should be grammatically correct, obviously. However, there is no rule that says that bulleted lists must contain only complete sentences.

Comment: And is it ok to ommit the noun? I thought that every english sentence must have the noun. Can the bullte list item be just "Provides this unique feature"?

Comment: No problem. You don't need a complete sentence since the context (subject) is already established.